# Counting data in ACCESS database?

Tags: c#, database, records, counting

I have 3 records in my database (database type : microsoft access ) . they are personal information of 3 Customers.

Now in interface I have button in the name of "Count Customers" . when I push it I want it to count records and says How many record(s) I have in Database ! .  for exmple here I have 3 , it must say you have 3 records or 3 cutomers .

I use Visual Studio 2008 , language is **C#** . my database is Microsoft **Access Database** .

Comment: You should not only state what you want, but also show what you have tried.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
   using (OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=C:\\Test.mdb"))
        using (OleDbCommand Command = new OleDbCommand(" SELECT count (CustomerId) from Customer as total", con))
        {
            con.Open();
            OleDbDataReader DB_Reader = Command.ExecuteReader();
            if (DB_Reader.HasRows)
            {
                DB_Reader.Read();
                int id = DB_Reader.GetInt32(0);
            }
        }
```

Comment: thank you . I use your code but it doesnt word , would you plz creat one and attach it so I can download it . thank you agian

Comment: what problem you are getting?

Comment: ALSO when I use GetInt it sys :    Error 1 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataReader' does not contain a definition for 'GetInt' and no extension method 'GetInt' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataReader' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) O:\C#\Shomareshe data\shomaresh data\shomaresh data\Form1.cs 39 47 shomaresh data

Comment: http://www.axofile.com/images/hfavtc4o1zxys4tv67b.png

Comment: http://www.axofile.com/images/shity9ufq92qiwlzy5d.png

Comment: Instead of GetInt will u plz try GetString()

Comment: unfortunately not worked !!      http://www.axofile.com/images/uaiv9bn9hl4v9xrka8eb.png

Comment: I locally created a database and i try this updated code, i hope it works for u.

Comment: thank you . finally it worked !! THANKSSSSS

Comment: now how can count specific records , for example count ONLY records that have empty rows ?

Comment: i am not sure but try this:-
 
select count(*) - count(ColumnName) as NumberOfNulls from yourTable and don't forget to up voat the answer.

Answer (score 2):

this simple query will return the total number of rows in a table

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table_name
```

Answer (score 1):

```
using (OledbConnection cn = new OledbConnection())
            {
                cn.ConnectionString = OledbConnectionString;
                cn.Open();

                OledbCommand commandRowCount = new OledbCommand("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [TABLENAME]", cn);
                countStart = System.Convert.ToInt32(commandRowCount.ExecuteScalar());
                MessageBox.Show("Starting row count: " + countStart.ToString());
            }
```

Comment: thank you so much , but I want to use it for WP not for DOS , if you have time please change it for C# WP .

Comment: WP?  This is the correct answer and nothing to do with DOS. It illustrates what you need to do.  You can change the MessageBox.Show line to whatever you need.

Comment: OK thank you , please see this errors and tell me what to do plz     http://www.axofile.com/images/4ayh5dqyjb1t22i79yas.png